# How to download a csv file requested through jquery/ajax from flask server

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I am building a python flask web app. I am trying to get a CSV file downloaded through jquery/ ajax call.

This is how my ajax request looks like:

```
$(".download-btn").on("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/downloadFile',
        contentType: 'csv',
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("coming");
        },
    });
```

and this is by server code looks like:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
path = os.getcwd()

@app.route('/downloadFile',methods = ['GET'])
def download():
    logger.info('Checking file to download..')
    logger.info(path)
    return send_file(path+"/Generated/modified_file.csv",
                        mimetype='text/csv',
                        attachment_filename='modified_file.csv',
                        as_attachment=True)
```

For your information, "modifed_file.csv" is present inside the path specified before the request is being made.

While running the code I can see

"Checking file to download.." and "coming" in output. But the file is not getting downloaded.

Also if I do

```
console.log(data);
```

I can see the content of the file.

I am stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code from `send_file` method? Certainly it is blocking the process.

Comment: send_file() is flask method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because the file's content is stored in the `data` variable (of the "success" callback of $.ajax), so it's just a js variable for the browser.

I think the best (cleanest maybe?) thing you can do is wrap your `.download-btn` in a `<a>` tag with your download url in href

```
<a href="/downloadFile" target="_blank">
    <button class="download-btn">Download</button>
</a>
```

This way "the browser itself" makes the GET request to `/downloadFile` (in a new tab because of the `target="_blank"` attribute), receives the stream and downloads the file (and closes tab once the download is started).

Comment: Can you give any other solution I can try with? Actually, The same button behaves differently based on the class assigned at particular time. Can't assign a particular href.

Comment: Maybe you can try changing the `href` attribute of `<a>` tag "accordingly" to the behaviour you expect?

Comment: yeah doing that. Thanks @Trio

Comment: Some time ago i had to download a CSV file generated from the browser page.
I link you a jsfiddle with an example. Dnt know if you can find it useful...

https://jsfiddle.net/ragu7yhm/1/

.

Some browser block `window.open` call as a popup, so i still advice to put the url in an `<a href="url">`.