# Flask send_file not working although the file exists

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

I've got an ajax call to a flask route. This ajax call is inside an onlick function of a button (because I have to send some preprocessed data). In the python code,I create a xlsx spreadhseet with 2 tabs and save the file in the server. Then I am trying to download it in the client but without success. No errors, and the response is 200 OK, but the file is not downloaded.
This is my python code:

```
@app.route('/download_file', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download_file():
    v1 = request.json['v1']
    v2 = request.json['v2']
    v1_df = pd.DataFrame(v1, columns=V1_HEADERS)
    v2_df = pd.DataFrame(v2, columns=V2_HEADERS)
    final_excel = f'resources/final_excel.xlsx'
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(final_excel, engine='xlsxwriter')
    v1_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='V1', index=False)
    v2_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='V2', index=False)
    writer.save()
    return send_file(final_excel, as_attachment=True, mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
```

I also tried `send_directory` without success.

What am I doing wrong? I'm a little desperate.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: have you had a look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me as though you may not be handling the returned `file` in your Ajax callback correctly. Since this is an Ajax call it will be returned to the relevant callback for you to handle.

So in your `.JS` code like below handle it as you wish, e.g.

```
 success:function(callback){
    var temp = 'file-> ' + callback;
    $(doc).text(temp)
 }
```

This may also help - [Download a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53740891/how-to-download-a-csv-file-requested-through-jquery-ajax-from-flask-server)